# Need way to edit the text that is pre-loaded into a python tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm hoping this is something that I'm overlooking, since I'm fairly new to Python, but I just can't figure this one out.  I have a root window with a menu.  When the user selects Open Project, a toplevel is created to display the data, the data is loaded from a file into a dictionary, and also loaded into Entry widgets to display the data for the user.  All that works fine.  The "title" appears on the left and the Entry text area appears to the right with the appropriate text loaded.

However, at that point, I can't edit the data.  Clicking on any of the Entry texts does nothing.  UNLESS I switch to the root window, then back to the toplevel.  Then I can edit the data.

I want to be able to edit the data right away, then click the "Update" button to re-save the data and update the dictionary.

I'm using Python 3.4 on Windows 8.1.

Here's the relevant code:

```
def displayData(self):
    tk = __import__("tkinter")

    self.projectStrVars = {}    # list of the StrVariables used for the Entry widgets

    # create the frame to hold the labels and entry widgets
    dataFrame = tk.LabelFrame(self.projectWin, width=800, height=458, text="Project Data: ")
    dataFrame.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=2, sticky='WE', padx=5, pady=5, ipadx=5, ipady=5)

    # populate the form Labels and Entry widgets with the data in self.projectData
    for index in range(self.numFields):
        key = self.formFields[index]
        value = self.projectData[key]
        tk.Label(dataFrame, text=key).grid(row = index+1, column = 0)
        self.projectStrVars[index] = tk.StringVar()
        self.entry = tk.Entry(dataFrame, textvariable = self.projectStrVars[index])
        self.entry.grid(row = index+1, column = 1)
        self.entry.insert(index, value)

    updateButton = tk.Button(dataFrame, text="Update", command=self.storeNewProjectData)
    updateButton.grid(row=20, column=0, columnspan=2)
```

Comment: Sounds like an interesting problem :-) Unfortunately, I can't properly investigate without an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Why are you importing tkinter using `__import__`?

Comment: @BryanOakley I found that code when searching for a way to import modules into a function.  I just changed it to "import tkinter as tk" as that seems to be more standard.  And it works fine, so I guess that's what counts.

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to figure out why I can't change the text until I alt-tab to the root window, then back to the toplevel.  If I try to highlight the text in one of the Entry widgets, it won't even highlight.  But if I switch to the root window, then back, it will suddenly appear highlighted as it should have at first.

Comment: I've had this same problem myself when trying to populate a root window and pop a `messagebox` in the class's `__init__()`. To solve it, I moved the `messagebox` calls to separate helper functions and called those functions with `after()` (e.g. `self.parent.after(1, make_message)`). Look through your program and try commenting out lines until you find the culprit, and then put whatever it's doing into a helper function and call it with `after()`. I can't help much more than that without an MCVE.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is part of a 300+ line class that's quite integrated, so an MCVE isn't really feasible.  I've managed to get the culprit narrowed down to this line:

Comment: filename = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=self.projectWin, **openFileOptions)
If I comment that out, then I can edit the Entry widgets properly. Though they have no data in them, as it has not been loaded from the file, but at least I can click in the Entry and have a cursor and enter text. Is the filedialog holding onto control or something?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I found the problem.  It came down to WHEN the toplevel was being created. I was originally calling it before accessing the file and loading the data into a dictionary. For whatever reason, that prevented the toplevel from getting control/focus (whatever it's called) until/unless I switched to the root window and then back.

I changed it so that the toplevel is being created right before the data is displayed to the user (after the file is opened and the data is loaded into the dictionary). Works great.